# Predecryption + File name encryption

Tags: encryption, luks, mediaserver, veracrypt, cryfs

I am using ubuntu server on an old 2011 imac. I want to encrypt a directory i use frequently with a method that hides the file names (like cryfs), but the encryption is only important for when the system is inactive so I need a method that predecrypts the entire directory when mounted, without using on the fly decryption (too slow). Does such a method exist?

It would be helpful for it to not require partition or predetermined size of directory like VeraCrypt but i will take what i can get at this point.

Thanks, John.